# How can I remove the border of the selected tab in HTML / CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the html and css for creating the horizontal tab bar in which I have some classes and a javascript function which bascially changes the tab based on the selection of the specific tab :

```js
function openPage(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}


/* Style the close button */

.topright {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.topright:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'AboutUs')">AboutUs</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'Careers')">Careers</button>
</div>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home Page.</p>
</div>

<div id="AboutUs" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>AboutUs</h3>
  <p>AboutUs page.</p>
</div>

<div id="Careers" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Careers</h3>
  <p>Careers Page.</p>
</div>
```

When I am running it , it is working correctly but there is a underline beneath the selected tab which I want to remove . Does anybody have the idea , how it can be removed  beneath the selected tab ?

Thanks

Comment: If you remove the underline, replace it with another focus style,

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove the active class? Not 100% clear what expected behavior really is here

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think he just wants the border to go under it when it's active, but also the border under the other buttons and the overlay needs to remain border for div. I guess he asked the question and ran away :)

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if I'm wrong, but do you want to get a look like this ?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    /* Style the tab */
    
    .tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-bottom: none;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    
    .tab button.active {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    /* Style the tab content */
    
    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
    }
    /* Style the close button */
    
    .topright {
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    .topright:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'AboutUs')">AboutUs</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'Careers')">Careers</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <p>Home Page.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="AboutUs" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
    <h3>AboutUs</h3>
    <p>AboutUs page.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Careers" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
    <h3>Careers</h3>
    <p>Careers Page.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openPage(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes something like this but need the border at the bottom of the tabs div but not under the selected tab

Answer (score 0):

the only changes are

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write code like this.

```
elm.style.textDecoration = "none";
```